# Why HTML background images not showing in live server in VS Code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, background-image, liveserver

I have a problem with live server in VS Code .

When I use a background image in my HTML code, it works properly when I open that file without live server. But when I try to open it using live server it dosn't show background images.

*****1. here is my html code*****
[my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sLNV.png)

**2. here is the output when i open it chrome without live server**
[output in chrome without live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYKMB.png)

3. **here is the output when i open it using live server**
   [output using live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rsXA.png)

Comment: Add your Folder Structure

Comment: give complete path to ```background="E:\complete_path"```

Comment: Please tell us your folder structure, their maybe an error in the `path`

Answer (score 4):

you should use either 'relative' paths of 'absolute' paths. Which means starting with a '/' (absolute) , or with a dot, '.' (relative).
On a live server environment a '/' points to your root website dir.

Make sure the image is in the same folder of your html, or a subfolder.

Your live server can not access your E: drive.

```
<img src="/image-in-root.jpg" alt="image in same dir as index.html"/>
or
<img src="./image-in-root.jpg" alt="image in same dir as index.html"/>

or
<img src="../../image-2-dirs-up.jpg" alt="image 2 dirs up from this file position"/>

or
<img src="/images/image-in-image-dir.jpg" alt="image in /image dir from root"/>
or
<img src="./images/image-in-image-dir.jpg" alt="image in /image dir one level below current"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the relative path for this problem of vs code live server.
If you are using external CSS then also use the relative path if the image is in the same folder or use the absolute path(full path) of the image if it is in another folder.

1. See the Output of my code I have to use the relative path of the image [CLICK HERE TO SEE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbltk.png)
2. This output is with the absolute path (Full Path) of the image [CLICK HERE TO SEE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfE0y.png)
3. [Relative Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqJZI.png)
4. [Absolute Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qp1k.png)

Comment: hey friends hope my Code picks and Output Picks help you!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly your solution does?

Comment: @CannedMan
If you use relative path for fixed image in the background the it will work and if you use full path then sometimes it won't work and the background image will not appear

Comment: If you elaborate on this in your answer, then I am sure you will get some upvotes once the solution has been verified. Answers should be self-contained, not be links to other sites, so try to include your code here as well, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: @CannedMan 
actually, these are not {  links to other sites } they are two different images and code that am trying to explain, one is the code & images of the relative path and one is of the full path.