# Visual Studio Code Live Server not showing images

Tags: html, image, file, visual-studio-code, liveserver

Very very new to all of this, When I use image in HTML code and try to open it using VS Code Live Server it doesn't show the image but it works properly when I open the file without LS. I have my root folder called code playground and my image is in sub-folder called images and the HTML code is the sub-folder called code. When I use image in HTML code and try to open it using VS Code Live Server it doesn't show the image but it works properly when I open the file without LS.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<img src="../images/crab.jpg">
```

Comment: can you send me the img of the folder? CTRL B for open the folder tab in vscode

Comment: use the LIVE SERVER that created by Ritwick Dey, this create a server but the the browser is outside vscode, is better than the preview (default of vscode)

Comment: Kindly check this thread if it would solve the problem.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997054/why-html-background-images-not-showing-in-live-server-in-vs-code)

Answer (score -1):

It may be from an ad blocker like Adblock.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No it's not ....