# How to change slider image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I insert images of a sun and moon (or any two images) in the slider so when it is clicked it will change the image based on when dark/light mode is enabled? I'm not sure how to go about this. I want to keep the slider as I like the transition but I want images inside of there showing a moon when lightmode is enabled to allow a user to click it for dark mode and the same for when it is in dark mode.

HTML:

```
<main id="main">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="darkLight()" id="checkBox" >
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
main p {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
/*TOGGLE COLORS*/
.dark {
  background: #545454;
  color: #efefef;
}
p {
  background: none !important;
}
/*SWITCH*/
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  align-self: center;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.slider:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#main').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

function darkLight() {
  /*DARK CLASS*/
  if (localStorage.toggled != 'dark') {
    $('#main, p').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";
     
  } else {
    $('#main, p').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
}

/*Add 'checked' property to input if background == dark*/
if ($('main').hasClass('dark')) {
   $( '#checkBox' ).prop( "checked", true )
} else {
  $( '#checkBox' ).prop( "checked", false )
}
```

Comment: You can respond automatically to light/dark mode using `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { ...your dark mode css here....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to put a background image inside the slider button, with CSS. You need an image URL for the selectors `.slider:before` and `input:checked + .slider:before`. Here's an example with some **imgur** URLs, but I would use your own just to guard against possible link removal in the future.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  align-self: center;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/6NVOxEL.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  /*background-color: white;*/
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
   background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/L8cR8EK.png");
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.slider:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">        
    <span class="slider">
   </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the reply. I was able to copy and paste your code into a code pen and it seems to work but when I copy and paste it into my css file it doesn’t seem to function as expected. The images do not appear, even after changing the images themselves. Would you happen to know off of the top of your head what could be causing that? I assumed conflicting css but I’ve removed it all to no avail.

Comment: @Jon I tried it with your code it works the same. Make sure the syntax is correct and you add 3 CSS lines: `background-image: url("http:://URL");` and `background-size: contain;` and `background-repeat: no-repeat;` Please upvote or select solved if the solution worked for you. :)

Comment: This appears to be a live server issue. Not sure why but it doesn't work with the live server. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jon oh strange. Apparently there has been an issue with background image CSS and live server. You may have luck storing an image locally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997054/why-html-background-images-not-showing-in-live-server-in-vs-code